# Can device run tensorflow lite be used as a work task when performing distribute training?

Tags: tensorflow

Can a device running tensorflow lite be used as a work task of parameter server when performing distribute training?

Answer (score 0):

At this point TensorFlow Lite performs only the forward pass (aka inference), not the back propagation (BP), so it doesn't fit into the training pattern (many iterations of forward and BP).

Plus, TensorFlow Lite is designed to be small and fast on resource constrained devices so it does not make much sense to try to use it in training.